# MacOS Monterey createinstallmedia Error : Failed to extract AssetData/boot/Firmware/Manifests/InstallerBoot/* from update bundle

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, error, monterey, bootable-disk

I'm trying to create a bootable USB with a MacOS Monterey disk image. I have a MacBook Pro Mid 2012 i5 (MacBookPro9,2). I'm using Open Core Legacy Patcher (OCLP) to run Monterey (macOS 12.4 21F79 - 12.1GB) since I'm aware that Apple has dropped support for MBP Mid 2012 after Catalina. I tried using OCLP to create the bootable USB however I get the following error:

```
Failed to create macOS installer
Output: Started erase on disk2
Unmounting disk
Creating the partition map
Waiting for partitions to activate
Formatting disk2s2 as Mac OS Extended with name OCLP-Installer
Initialized /dev/rdisk2s2 as a 29 GB case-insensitive HFS Plus volume
Mounting disk
Finished erase on disk2
Making disk bootable...
Error: 2022-06-20 12:51:36.026 OCLP-Helper\[18958:154311\] Starting...
Erasing disk: 0%... 10%... 20%... 30%... 100%
Failed to extract AssetData/boot/Firmware/Manifests/InstallerBoot/\* from update bundle
The bless of the installer disk failed.
2022-06-20 12:56:28.738 OCLP-Helper\[18958:154311\] Done
```

I tried running the equivalent commands in the terminal however I get the same error.

```
~
❯ sudo su
Password:
sh-3.2# /Applications/Install\ macOS\ Monterey.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia --volume /Volumes/Untitled
Ready to start.
To continue we need to erase the volume at /Volumes/Untitled.
If you wish to continue type (Y) then press return: y
Erasing disk: 0%... 10%... 20%... 30%... 100%
Making disk bootable...
Failed to extract AssetData/boot/Firmware/Manifests/InstallerBoot/* from update bundle
The bless of the installer disk failed.
sh-3.2#
```

My USB is 32GB. Does this have anything to do with my USB? I had previously used to create a Fedora bootable USB and then I erased it using Disk Utility in my MacBook. Any help would be appreciated since I have been trying to solve this however I can't find any resource online that addresses this. Thank you in advance!

Comment: How large is the Install macOS Monterey application?